# When does duplicate digest computations warrant redesign in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have been working with AngularJS for a while now and this is one subject I still am not sure about.  Let me start with an example.  In my site I have a table with data. I want to be able to search/sort/filter this data in a number of ways. We have a search box that utilizes the built in "filter" filter to search the data. We also have a number of other filters that allows the user to check checkboxes and get different views (think Amazon).

The issue is because things like pagination need to know about these filters and must apply its computations based off the filtered view of data, not the original data set.

Doing so makes our HTML look like this:

```
<div class="row paginationInfo clearfix">
            <div class="col-xs-3 showResultsWrap">
                <span data-name="summary"><b>{{ getPageStart2((model.IndividualMailboxes.filtered | pipe:model.IndividualMailboxes.filters.functions:model.IndividualMailboxes.filters.values), model.IndividualMailboxes.currentPage, model.IndividualMailboxes.resultsPerPage) }} - {{ getPageEnd2((model.IndividualMailboxes.filtered | pipe:model.IndividualMailboxes.filters.functions:model.IndividualMailboxes.filters.values), model.IndividualMailboxes.currentPage, model.IndividualMailboxes.resultsPerPage) }}</b> of <b>{{ (model.IndividualMailboxes.filtered | pipe:model.IndividualMailboxes.filters.functions:model.IndividualMailboxes.filters.values).length }}</b></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-xs-center">
                <div max-size="5" boundary-links="true" first-text="«" last-text="»" previous-text="&lsaquo;" next-text="&rsaquo;" uib-pagination ng-show="(model.IndividualMailboxes.filtered | pipe:model.IndividualMailboxes.filters.functions:model.IndividualMailboxes.filters.values).length > 10" total-items="(model.IndividualMailboxes.filtered | pipe:model.IndividualMailboxes.filters.functions:model.IndividualMailboxes.filters.values).length" ng-model="model.IndividualMailboxes.currentPage" items-per-page="model.IndividualMailboxes.resultsPerPage" class="pagination-md"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 resultsPerPageWrap form-inline text-xs-right">
                <span>View</span>
                <select sk-id-gen="resultsPerPage" name="ResultsPerPage" class="form-control m-l-1" ng-model="model.IndividualMailboxes.resultsPerPage" ng-options="val as val for val in [10, 20, 50, 100]">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The important thing to notice here is how many times we have to do `(hereIsMyArray | pipe:param1:param2).length` over and over again for the pagination to work.

So correct me if I am wrong, but I believe every digest cycle we are running these pipes/filters 5+ times.  This is probably OK with a small dataSet, but if I start having to filter 10,000 items then I'm sure I will see performance issues.

It would be much more efficient if we only had to do the pipe/filtering 1 time and each of these HTML components could just use that single instance of the filtered data set.

The issue with not doing it directly in the HTML is you no longer have automatic watches setup to see when data changes and updates the view.

If any of my statements are wrong please let me know. I am curious if anyone has had this issue before and has a solution?

Thanks

Comment: For complex filter situations, it's often astronomically better for performance to inject the filter into the controller and conduct the filtering there.  You can then use the once-filtered result directly in the view.  Here is a little unintuitive factoid:  *Every* single DOM filter gets analyzed in every digest cycle, even when the corresponding data has not changed.  This slows down the app much faster than you'd think.  See this article for more:   https://toddmotto.com/use-controller-filters-to-prevent-digest-performance-issues/

Comment: So the question here becomes, how do you trigger the filter to happen on all digest cycles if you put the filter logic in the controller? Do you use $watches or some other method?  I have tried this method before without much luck because it makes syncing the UX/viewmodel harder.

Comment: I should restate that... not ALL digest cycles. But I have a number of different controls on the page that all change how the filters should work (i.e. typing into an input for search or checking a box for a filter). Before it "just worked" because it was in the HTML. Now it would need something to tell it to update

Comment: Ok so I guess I will just need `ng-change` on every single input / checkbox  in question here which is near 15-20 (we have about 15 filters with checkboxes that the user can use to filter the view).

Comment: Exactly. Assuming you're using `$scope`, this should be enough: `<input type="checkbox" ng-change="doFilter()" />`. And create the corresponding `$scope.doFilter` function which will analyze all of the models of the checkboxes and then run the filter accordingly.  This is ideal in every way.  Performance is greatly improved where applicable and the view is cleaner too.

Comment: Ok I will give that method a try. Thanks